# I'm stuck with CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

I'm seriously stuck with CocoaPods. Please help!

Can someone please tell me where i'm going wrong? I'm doing an online Objective-C course. I've been stuck on CocoaPods for far too long. I completed the CocoaPods course and seem to have installed everything correctly.

I have followed these steps in line with this tutorial:

1) I created a podfile within the PhotoBombers Xcode project.

2) Within Xcode I clicked on the podfile, then entered: pod 'SimpleAuth/Instagram'

3) I then searched for the Terminal using Spotlight. Within the terminal I then entered 'pod' and pressed enter (as shown in the tutorial), however the following code appeared and looked nothing like the code in the tutorial:

Usage:

$ pod COMMAND

CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
Commands:

- cache      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
- init       Generate a Podfile for the current directory.
- install    Install project dependencies to Podfile.lock versions
- ipc        Inter-process communication
- lib        Develop pods
- list       List pods
- outdated   Show outdated project dependencies
- plugins    Show available CocoaPods plugins
- repo       Manage spec-repositories
- search     Search for pods.
- setup      Setup the CocoaPods environment
- spec       Manage pod specs
- trunk      Interact with the CocoaPods API (e.g. publishing new specs)
- try        Try a Pod!
- update     Update outdated project dependencies and create new
           Podfile.lock
  Options:

--silent     Show nothing
--version    Show the version of the tool
--verbose    Show more debugging information
--no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
--help       Show help banner of specified command

Comment: Use `pod init` to set up CocoaPods in your project.

Comment: Thanks, would I put this into the podfile within Xcode, or the Terminal?

Comment: You should put it in Terminal.

Please rephrase your question, it's too broad